# Getting all meanings of field in ArrayList | Firebase

Tags: java, android, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using `Firebase Realtime database` in my Android app. How can I query field `Ingridients` in my database and get all meanings in `ArrayList`?

There is structure of my database:

```
{
  "Receptes" : [ {
    "Ingridients" : [ "Carrot", "Salt", "Apples" ],
    "Name" : "Food"
  } ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: what do you mean `get all meanings`?

Comment: I mean that I need get `Carrot`,`Salt` and `Apples` into my `ArrayList`

Comment: Could you edit the question to show the code that you've tried that's not working the way you expect?

Comment: At first glance it looks like you're trying to use an array for storing a set of data. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value) for why it's not possible to query recipes based on their ingredients with this structure, and how to instead structure your database to allow the query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although Firebase Realtime database can store arrays, it does not support querying array members or updating single array elements. So to solve this, I recommend you an alternative database structure that looks like this:

```
{
  "Receptes" : {
    "Ingridients" : {
      "Carrot" : true,
      "Salt" : true,
      "Apples" : true
    },
    "Name" : "Food"
  }
}
```

As you can see, now the `Receptes` and the `Ingridients` are stored as a `Maps` and not as an arrays. And to query your database to display all ingridients, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference ingridientsRef = rootRef.child("Receptes").child("Ingridients");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String ingridient = ds.getKey();
            Log.d("TAG", ingridient);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
ingridientsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

According to your comment, the database should look like this:

```
{
  "Receptes" : {
    "Ingridients" : {
      "IngridientIdOne" : {
        "Carrot" : true,
        "Salt" : true,
        "Apples" : true
      },
      "IngridientIdTwo" : {
        "Strawberries" : true,
        "Sugar" : true,
        "Bananas" : true
      },
    },
    "Name" : "Food"
  }
}
```

Comment: But how will the structure of the database look like with a lot of recipes? And how can I get the `Name` of each unique recept?

Comment: You can achieve this by adding an ingredient id under the `Ingridients` node, as in my updated answer. See, IngridientIdOne, IngridientIdTwo?

Comment: Okay. How can I get values `IngridientIdOne` and `IngridientIdTwo` in this `ValueEventListener`?

Comment: As you can see in my code, to query your database, those ids are not needed. But if you want to have them, just store those ids in a variable when adding the ingridients, right?

Comment: why when I  using your code line `String ingridient = ds.getKey();` is not return ingridients but return `IngridientIdOne`?

Comment: Because `ds.getKey()` returns the key and the value. That's why.

Answer (score 0):

```
DatabaseReference recept = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Receptes");
DatabaseReference vegies = recept.child("Ingridients");
```

Check the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#get_a_databasereference) for more explanation.

You also need to add a listener

```
recept.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.i(TAG, dataSnapshot.child("Ingredients").getValue(String.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.w(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    }
});
```

Comment: For my strucuture of database your code will return `null`